# How to Convert Range of Integers into PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to convert these integers/numbers:

```
$groups = '1707,1723,1733,16254,16256,18704,19792,29268,34956';
```

into an array in PHP array:

```
array("1707","1723","1733","29268","34956");
```

I'm using this

```
 $tags = array();
 foreach($groups as $index){
     array_push($tags, $index);
  }
```

But keep getting the below error.

```
 Error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: Use [explode](http://www.php.net/explode): `explode(",", $groups);` You probably have to [trim](http://www.php.net/trim) the individual results afterwards in case your input is something like `1707, 1723, 1733` etc. (spaces after commas)

Comment: Do you want to remove `16254,16256,18704,19792`?

Comment: Read about [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). It expects an array (or an object that implements `Iterable`) but you provide it a string. It doesn't work this way. [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) splits your string into pieces and produces an array. You don't even need to iterate over it as it produces the `$tags` you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple [explode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) call:

```
$array=explode(',',$groups);
```

Answer (score 1):

The explode() function breaks a string into an array.

```
$groups = '1707,1723,1733,16254,16256,18704,19792,29268,34956';
print_r(explode(",",$groups));
```